# Tensorflow stops being recognized

Tags: pip, pycharm, virtualenv, vmware, tensorflow

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed through VMWare.
I had tensorflow installed in a virtualenv and I imported it to pycharm and worked with it without problems.
Today I started pycharm and it looked like it is the first time I am starting it. Then when I tried to run a python file that I ran last month and it's not working, saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/TensorFlowTutorials/mnist_beginner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist
```

Then I tried installing it (without knowing why,since it was installed last month) through `sudo pip install tensorflow` and it says:

```
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting tensorflow
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow**
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Any idea what caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your config has been blown away, which would include the configured Python path. Since you're using a virtualenv, you'll need to configure PyCharm to use it under Project Settings > Project Interpreter and selecting or browsing to the Python executable in your virtualenv.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work and when I try to add an executable ("/home/user/tensorflow/bin/python2.7") named python2.7 (the virtualenv is named tensorflow here) as the interpreter it says "exit with non-zero code(4)", it also doesn't explain why when I am trying to reinstall tensorflow via pip it says:`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow` because it is outside Pycharm.

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't appear to be part of the PyPI at this time, follow the instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation
Also, make sure you're using the correct pip executable (the one in your virtualenv) when you install. Use `which pip` to confirm